# Does SenML provide any fields that describe the sensor itself?

Tags: interoperability, semantics

I am trying to look into the aspect of sending *meaningful* information from sensor nodes with the whole field of IoT. Here, *meaningful* being **context-aware**.

> If I send information from a temperature sensor, it might not be enough just to send the numerical value e.g. `24.9` to a gateway. It would make sense to add information like `unit of measurement`, `who is sending this information`, `where is the sensor node situated within the network` etc.

This would provide information where one would make more sense out huge information collected from IoT systems (think, Semantics IoT).

For this I found [SenML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8428) which provides nice data format to make sense of the information. In the RFC an example is described as follows:

```
[
     {"n":"urn:dev:ow:10e2073a01080063","u":"Cel","v":23.1}
]
```

where `n` is the name of the device `u` is the unit `v` is the actual value from the sensing unit. The RFC is very well described for many cases including batch uploading as well as timestamps.

However it does not provide any field that provides some *context-awareness* of the sensing unit. For e.g. is the temperature above from `"outside"` or `"inside"` or in `"car"` etc.

Does someone know any other data-format or sensor modelling language that supports some form of context awareness. If not, what could be a possible way around this in `senML`?

Comment: yes, but I can't remember what to search for now. However, context is in the eye of the consumer. Its correct that some people aim to publish data in a way that meets your expectations. If it were me, I'd make something up though.

Comment: I believe not only in the eyes of the consumer but also when it comes to deployment, development, maintainence. Wouldn't it make sense for e.g. to query a database which provides `give me all sensors from list where placement='outside'` ?

Comment: you could have the nodes publish the data to an MQTT server  .... see these https://shiftr.io/shiftr-io/demo and https://shiftr.io/shiftr-io/try

Comment: @jsotola I don't see how that would make sense in accordance to the query I asked.